# Late 80s/ early 90s anthology of scary stories: cover art had a boy running away from a shadowy figure at a campfire

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror, anthology-book

I got this either at a book fair or from the book store. It had several (probably 13) different stories. I don’t remember if they were different authors. I remember four premises. Although they could possibly be from separate collections.

- One, a boy gets separated from his scout troop and wanders up to another campfire and sees a man with blood dripping from his mouth. There’s an emphasis on his heavy footsteps as the boy is chased through the woods.
- Two, a married couple where the wife was told to never feed her husband red meat. One day she decides to see why the warning and he turns into a werewolf.
- Three, a young girl attends a Halloween party but she’s had nightmares about a vampire lately. She avoids men costumed as such and a charming blond man rescues her and takes her out on the lake, only to reveal that he is the vampire.
- Four, two or three girls are having a sleepover over at one friend’s bungalow (I remember that specifically), and there’s a warning about going outside… I just remember the *scriiitch* as something comes closer to the home. The creature is scratching the walls.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 9):

*[Night Frights](https://archive.org/details/nightfrightsthir00stam/)* by Judith Stamper has "Night Woods" with the scout who encounters the man with the bloody teeth, "Nightmare" with a girl at a sleepover at a "bungalow", and "Coming to Get You" with the description of the scritching and scratching at the walls. Also, that cover matches.

[image: Front cover of Night Frights]

*[Still More Tales for the Midnight Hour](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/301465)* by the same author has two more of the stories. The vampire story is "The Masked Ball". The werewolf story is "A Special Treat".

"Night Woods" seems to have also been presented as "A Night in the Woods" in [*More Tales for the Midnight Hour*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?22845) as per [Short story about werewolf killing 'boy scout'-type campers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166111/short-story-about-werewolf-killing-boy-scout-type-campers/)

For what it's worth, I found the werewolf husband book with a search for `horror book husband red meat`, which led to [this Reddit TOMT query](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/ami6p3/comment/efp6bhq/), which then led me to look up a copy of the book on archive.org, and search other books on there by the author.

Comment: I can confirm, recognized the red meat story and that was the cover art